# Placing divs underneath each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place a div underneath other div's. Instead of being placed underneath each other they overlay.

An overview of how the page looks:
I am using bootstrap to style it. I am using a fixed navbar with the brand logo in the middle. Underneath the navigation bar I placed an image.

The div for the navbar and for the image stack nicely but when I try to add another div underneath the image it instead overlays with the image and goes underneath the navbar not underneath the image.

Ideally I would like to place the navbar and image divs inside container but I have had no success in trying to do so.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>welcome</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- AnjularJs -->
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

  <!-- css files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="navBar.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand">Name</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Navigation Bar -->

    <div class="arrow"></div>

    <!--Image-->
    <div class=bkgimage><h1>Slogan</h1></div>
    <!--End of image -->

    <!-- Want to add another div here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

navBar.css

```
body {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  display:inline-block;
  float:none;
  color:white;

  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-style:italic;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
.navbar {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #00b3b3;
  border:none;
}
.arrow {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-left:20px solid transparent;
  border-right:20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #00b3b3;
  z-index:2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color:white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
  color:white;
}
.bkgimage {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('test.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:75%;
}
.bkgimage h1 {
  color:  white;

  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-style:italic;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;

  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: When you add position: absolute; to anything, you remove it from the natural flow of the page, so the next item will not follow it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `.bkgimage` div has `position: absolute` the next div doesn't know the .bkimage divs position and naturally goes to the bottom of the next block level element which is positioned relatively e.g. your `.navbar-fixed-top` div.

One quick fix here looking at your css would be to use relative positioning and viewport height measurement for the size of container the following for your .bkimage div:

```
.bkimage{
 position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x250');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:75vh;
}
```

and for your .bkgimage h1 Set margin-top to -20px (to push under the arrow) and instead use padding-top: 150px which fixes your box model layout for this container (your margin pushes down from the previous div, your padding pushes down the internal content of a div e.g.

```
.bkgimage h1 {
  color:  white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-style:italic;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Also as Koschtik mentions, you need to address the structure of your HTML for Bootstrap to work properly. The above fix works with your current HTML, but you will run into problems quite rapidly with markup structured like that

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use float CSS rather than the position attribute.

Firstly add height 100% to the body and html:

```
html, body {
   height:100%;
}
```

Change .bkgimage to float instead of position:

```
.bkgimage {
   float:left;
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7hpp84jq/1/)